# Open Source Licence Reformulated

Tags: licensing

OK, Zizouz212 I will try to reformulate my question making it as clear as I can. I have a tool that is not open source but allows you to define plugins that have to follow a set of interfaces, all of them on a DLL. I also want to offer the source code for a plugin I developed as an example of how to implement those interfaces. I want to release the source code for those interfaces in C# so that people can use it as documentation on how to build the plugins. Which open source licence do you think I should use for both the interfaces and the example plugin? If you think my question is still unclear, please feel free to lead me in the right direction!

Comment: Your question is clearer now but this is not the way to do it. Please edit [your old question](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/4437/kind-of-open-source-licence) and delete this one. Then the people who down-voted will have the opportunity to cancel their vote and @Zizouz212 will have the opportunity to lift the ban.